# infinity loop js change title

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can change the title of my site in infinity loop? When message comes function `changeTitle()` is executed for a while to click on user button, but when infinity loop is running I can not do anything.

*function ClickButton*

```
$("#userButton").click(function(){
    $("#hNot").val("");
});
```

*function changeTitle and sleep*

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

function changeTitle() {
    do {
        document.title = "New message...";
        sleep(1000);
        var text = "From " + $("#hNot").val() + "...";
        document.title = text;
        sleep(1000);

    } while ($("#hNot").val() != "") {
        document.title = "title default";
    }
};
```

Comment: This is just terrible what you are doing. You should not block entire UI thread like this with endless loops. Use events.

Comment: Your `sleep` should not have a `loop`. You can/should use a `timeout`.

Comment: You can change the title in the keypress/blur event of the input and/or in the button click. In this way you can avoid loops or timeout?

Comment: Oh god... sleep in Javascript. You should use setTimeout instead or setInterval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function with a `setTimeout`, not any loop (a loop will block the entire UI during it execution time, so for ever in your case):

```
function changeTitle(type) {
    if ($("#hNot").val() != "") {
        if (type === 1) {
            document.title = "New message...";
            type = 0;
        } else {
            document.title = "From " + $("#hNot").val() + "...";
            type = 1;
        }
        setTimeout(function(){ changeTitle(type) }, 1000);
    } else {
        document.title = "tittle default";
    }
}
changeTitle(1); //launch title change
```